# Calling all class with some same character/pharse

Tags: html, css

I have 10 classes with the same start of name (i.e: `.ota-1st`, `ota-2nd`... and so on) but all have different `background-color`.

I want to apply to those classes with same properties.

I remember once I saw some code like `.ota-{margin-top:20px}`, kind of that.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the attribute selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```css
div[class*="ota-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ota-1">yep</div>
<div class="ota-2">yep</div>
<div class="ota-">yep</div>
<div class="foo">nope</div>
<div class="ota">nope</div>
<div class="asdf-ota-1">nope</div>
```